# Automatically check & connect map network drive when disconnected

Tags: batch-file, networking, window

I have a batch file which has the following command:

```
@echo off 
net use z: /Delete
net use z: \\myIpAddress\SharedFolder Password /user:Administrator /presistent:yes
```

this works fine every time I open the pc because it is located in the startup folder. What I am trying to do is to check every number of minutes whether the network drive is mapped or not and if not it can connect automatically. is that possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
@echo off 
dir \\myIpAddress\SharedFolder\dummyfile.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 GOTO createdrive

exit

:createdrive
net use z: /Delete
net use z: \\myIpAddress\SharedFolder Password /user:Administrator /presistent:yes
```

This batchfile can be placed in your taskscheduler with a repeat of 1 minute or whatever you want.